# Creating a dynamic Javascript/jQuery Web-based Terminal to an arbitary IP Address

Tags: javascript, jquery, ssh, terminal, telnet

So here is the challenge;

I want to be able to fire off a web-based terminal from within my existing (server-side created) page.

The idea is that it queries a SQL table and provides a list of IP address/Port details, and with a single click the user is connected to the Telnet/SSH interface at that address:port

My front-end makes heavy use of Javascript/jQuery, and I'd like to avoid too much back-end stuff (which is in classic ASP - don't mock!)

Any ideas gratefully appreciated!

Comment: You could check the approach which uses yes (it's an chrome extension ) https://github.com/krasimir/yez

Comment: unfortunately I won't be allowed to use browser extensions, and it has to work with IE10/FF/Opera/Chrome

Comment: It would still be useful to know _how_ the extension achieved it, whether or not it is an extension is irrelevant.

Comment: seems to use node.js, which is the route I'm looking at the moment (https://github.com/chjj/tty.js/)